# Collision Detection

Tags: java, collision, detection

I am new to Java, and I have basic programming knowledge. I have recently started developing a game(with the help of tutorials). The game is an RPG. It is set so that the player's avatar is constantly in the center of the screen, but the background scrolls. I know this has been asked before, but none of the answers make sense to me. Basically, how do I create collision detection for multiple objects? I want it to be so that my player stops moving when he hits a wall. I currently have collision for the boundaries set, but how do I set collision for houses, walls, etc.? A copy of my code is below. Thank you in advance. Also, I am using Slick2D.

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
//Need "extends etc." for creating basic screen/state
public class Play extends BasicGameState{

public Rectangle lake1;

Animation avatar, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft,  movingRight;
Image worldMap;
boolean quit = false;
int[] duration = {200,200};
float avatarPositionX = 0;
float avatarPositionY = 0;
float shiftX = avatarPositionX + 250;
float shiftY = avatarPositionY + 180;

public Play(int state){
}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{   
    worldMap = new Image("res/WaterMap.png");
    Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/CharBack.png"), new 
Image("res/CharBack.png")};
    Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/CharFront.png"), new 
Image("res/CharFront.png")};
    Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/CharLeft.png"), new  
Image("res/CharLeft.png")};
    Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/CharRight.png"), new
Image("res/CharRight.png")};

    movingUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
    movingDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);
    movingLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);
    movingRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);
    avatar = movingDown;
}
//Takes gc and StateBasedGame and Graphics
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws    
SlickException{
    lake1 = new Rectangle(132, 277, 87, 54);
    worldMap.draw(avatarPositionX, avatarPositionY);
    avatar.draw(shiftX, shiftY);
    g.drawString("Your X: "+avatarPositionX+"\nYour Y: "+avatarPositionY, 350,  
20);

    if(quit==true){
        g.drawString("Resume (R)", 200, 100);
        g.drawString("Main Menu (M)", 200, 150);
        g.drawString("Quit (Q)", 200, 200);
        if(quit==false){
            g.clear();
        }
    }
}
//Updates images on screen; creates animation
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws   
SlickException{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    //up
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
        avatar = movingUp;
        avatarPositionY += delta * .1f;
        //+= changed to -=
        if(avatarPositionY>180){
            avatarPositionY -= delta * .1f;
        }
    }
    //down
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
        avatar = movingDown;
        avatarPositionY -= delta * .1f;
        if(avatarPositionY<-497){
            avatarPositionY += delta * .1f;
        }
    }
    //left
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
        avatar = movingLeft;
        avatarPositionX += delta * .1f;
        if(avatarPositionX>249){
            avatarPositionX -= delta * .1f;
        }
    }
    //right
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
        avatar = movingRight;
        avatarPositionX -= delta * .1f;
        if(avatarPositionX<-433){
            avatarPositionX += delta * .1f;
        }
    }
    //escape
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
        quit = true;
    }
    //when menu is up
    if(quit == true){
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_R)){
            quit = false;
        }
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M)){
            sbg.enterState(0);
        }
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Q)){
            System.exit(0);
        }   
    }
}

public int getID(){
    return 1;
}
}
```

Comment: @Cruncher It is not tile-based as of yet. In the future, I would like it to be. If you have any suggestions at all though, be my guest. I am serious about creating this game, so any and all help is welcome!

Comment: As a reference, I'm envisioning something like Tibia. Essentially when you move, you can't stop moving until it moves a whole tile. Then at that point, you only need a 2d array of Tile objects. If the tile you are moving to has tile.passable() as true, then allow the walk, otherwise fail it

Comment: @Cruncher That makes a lot of sense! I'll have to look into implementing that method. It looks like I have some Googling to do.

Answer (score 0):

Before you actually move the character, check if the next position is 'empty' and inside the boundaries (how you actually implement this depends on how you implement your houses and walls) and only move the character if it is.

For the implementation you probably want to iterate over every 'object' and check if the new position of the character is inside it.

Comment: I plan on using a .tmx file to add a tiled map. Do you have any idea how I would be able to implement this? Thanks.